# Passing regexp as a query to postgresql database instead of array of options in rails

Tags: regex, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to search for unique models with the association where the attribute '*description*' of the associated model includes a word from a search query. I would like to find models only with an exact match e.g. if a user is searching for '*egg*', I would like the search to include models with '*description*' including e.g.: 'egg', 'eggs', 'egg,', 'eggs,', 'Egg' etc. but I don't want the search to include a model with '*eggplant*' within its *description* attribute. Therefore I am providing an array of options so the search will pick up everything that is an exact match and it is at the beginning, the middle and the end of the *description* and also, if the word from the query exists in plural version within the *description* or it is followed by a comma.

```
options = [
            "#{query} %",
            "#{query}s %",
            "#{query}s,%",
            "#{query},%",
            "% #{query} %",
            "% #{query}s %",
            "% #{query}s,%",
            "% #{query},%",
            "% #{query}s",
            "% #{query}"
          ]


@response ||= Model.joins(:associated_models).where(AssociatedModel.arel_table[:name].matches_any(options)).distinct
```

The above works, however, I was wondering if there is a better way perhaps by passing a RegExp into the query instead of the array of options e.g.:

**EDIT**

```
# query is either at the beginning of the description or is following the white space or it is followed by the white space or comma or an 's'
regexp_query = /(^|\s)#{query}($|\s|,)/

@response ||= Model.joins(:associated_models).where(AssociatedModel.arel_table[:name].matches(regexp_query)).distinct

or

@response ||= Model.joins(:associated_models).where('associated_models.name ILIKE ?', regexp_name).distinct
```

I have tried to use '**REGEXP**' or '**~***' instead of '**ILIKE**' but getting errors like -**can't quote Regexp** or -**PG::SyntaxError: ERROR: syntax error at or near "REGEXP"**

Comment: Instead of `[^|\s]`, use `(^|\s)`, and instead of `[\s|,|$]` use `($|[\s,])`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, valid point, thank you but I am still getting ```TypeError - can't quote Regexp```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered a similar error and in my case, it was resolved by using [Regexp#source](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/Regexp.html#method-i-source) to get the String expected by [ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#where](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where):

```
>> User.where("name ~ ?", /foo/)
TypeError: can't quote Regexp

>> User.where("name ~ ?", (/foo/).source)
=> []
```